# How to find column number of HTML table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to find out the column number that a td belongs to using jQuery.

For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row1, Column1</td>
        <td>Row1, Column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalRow">
        <td>Row2, Column1</td>
        <td class="columnChild">Row2, Column2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to find the column number for the cell with a class of `columnChild`. I know that it is the second child of `.totalRow`, and is the second column in the table, but how do I find this?

Eventually what I want to achieve is to add this to an array so I could have to columns with a class of `columnChild` and add these to the array, so I can then run a function for each row of a table on the second child.

I've tried writing this several times, but I'm hitting a bit of coders block so any help would be greatly appreciated. If you  require any more info, let me know and I'll provide what I can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the index of the td in the tr, you can simply use

```
var index = $('.columnChild').index();
```

If you have several cells with this class and you want their index in an array (I'm not sure I understand the second question starting with "Eventually"), you can do

```
var indexes = $('.columnChild').map(function(){return $(this).index()});
```

Comment: Perfect - so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

> so I can then run a function for each row of a table on the second child.

This will give you an array of td elements with class .columnChild (within tr elements with class totalRow).

```
$(".totalRow .columnChild")

this will allow to iterate through the array

 $(".totalRow .columnChild")

 .each(function (index, element)
{

  // element is the tr element

  // your function
});
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Please have a look at the toolbar when editing your answer. There even is a link to some help. When you select some code, you can hit Ctrl-K to make it appear as code.

Comment: Correction: element is a td element inside each function